# Compiling a vector from a recursive function in R

Tags: r, recursion, scope

I'm trying to understand how scoping works within recursive functions in R.

The context is this function that is supposed to return all unique combinations of a vector's elements. (The details of the exact desired output aren't really relevant here.)

```
perm <- function(x) {
    n <- length(x)
    if (n == 1) {
        print(x)
    } else {
        y <- NULL
        for (i in 1:n) {
            y <- paste(x[i], perm(x[-i]), sep = "_")
        }
        print(y)
    }
}
```

When I print the objects that I know I want to be returned (here, `print(x)` and `print(y)`), I get the correct values returned to the console just as print output:

```
perm(c("a","b","c"))
```

However, when I try to collect these in a vector, the resulting vector contains many orders of magnitude more elements than were printed. I suspect this is something to do with the recursion, but it seems strange given that the `print` functions are only being triggered sensibly. For example, and using a global variable to keep track of the output to ignore any scoping issues:

```
out <- c()
perm <- function(x) {
    n <- length(x)
    if (n == 1) {
        assign('out', c(out, x), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    } else {
        y <- NULL
        for (i in 1:n) {
            y <- paste(x[i], perm(x[-i]), sep = "_")
        }
        assign('out', c(out, y), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
}

perm(c("a","b","c"))
out
```

The first example prints only ten values, whereas in the second example, `out` is of length 56 and contains values that are not found in the first example (e.g., `"c_c"`). I know that assigning a vector this way is terribly inefficient, but I'm just trying to figure out how the scoping works and why these results are so different. I wouldn't have thought that there would be any scoping issues with the `print` function, i.e., every time `print(x)` or `print(y)` is triggered I'd expect the output to be printed to the console.

The same thing occurs when I assign `out` to the parent frame rather than the global environment, i.e., `out <<- c(out, x)`. Funnily enough, if I just use the `print` syntax, I can compute large numbers of combinations easily; but when using vector assignments, anything over four elements results in a recursive mess that fries the system.

So I guess the questions are,

1. Why does it seem to be triggering the vector assignment more frequently that the `print` function, when they're called in the same place?
2. Is there a better way to implement this sort of function?

The `perm` function is based on one of the functions found in [this blog post](https://blog.ephorie.de/learning-r-permutations-and-combinations-with-base-r).

Comment: If `n > 1`, your first function returns `y` (because that's what `print` invisibly returns). In the same case, your second function returns `out` (because that's what `assign` invisibly returns). Return values are important in recursion. I suggest explicit use of the `return` function until you gain a better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why does it seem to be triggering the vector assignment more frequently that the print function, when they're called in the same place?

The issue is that `print` returns the first argument while `assign` returns the assigned value. Take:

```r
b <- assign("a", 2)
b
#R> [1] 2
```

Thus, your function should be:

```r
out <- c()
perm <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  if (n == 1) {
    assign('out', c(out, x), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    x
  } else {
    y <- NULL
    for (i in 1:n) {
      y <- paste(x[i], perm(x[-i]), sep = "_")
    }
    assign('out', c(out, y), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    y
  }
}

perm(c("a","b","c"))
#R> [1] [1] "c_b_a"
out
#R> [1] "c"     "b"     "c_b"   "c"     "a"     "c_a"   "b"     "a"     "b_a"   "c_b_a"
```